# jquery event mechanism performance

Tags: jquery, performance, events

If I bind 3 events handlers to a jTarget element like this:

```
function doo1(){}
function doo2(){}
function doo3(){}

- jTarget.on('mouseover.my1', doo1);
- jTarget.on('mouseover.my2', doo2);
- jTarget.on('mouseover.my3', doo3);
```

Will it consume 3 times as much (time or perf) as if I was doing the following? :

```
- jTarget.on('mouseover.my3', function(){
    doo1();
    doo2();
    doo3();
});
```

Or in other words, does jquery handle some kind of event handling optimization internally ?

I need to know this because it would be more handy for me if I could
just use the first synopsis, rather than implementing the second.

Comment: The two snippets are entirely different in functional wise.. what's your problem?

Comment: In the first approach extra handlers will be attached hence will consume more memory.. but that is going to be insignificant unless you're gonna implement this in large scale

Comment: @TJ: that's what I thought. That's my answer thanks.  Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy: I want to implement a widget which can have native events bound to it, but also on which the user can attach her own events, so I wanted to see which approach would be better for this. The first approach is clearly easier for me to implement, as I don't need extra work. But for consuming events like mouseover, using the first approach might crash the widget, so I will have to implement a mechanism that only fire one event of mouseover type, and would actually trigger the widget native events AND the user events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://jsperf.com/jquery-event-performace-check

I created a simple snippet , shows attaching more events is slower.